# TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have two errors associated with one module in Joomla 2.5. I am interested in fixing them but, but to be specific I want to focus on the:

TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function

The error is on line 154 which is: "jQuery("ul.ext-menu").superfish({" and the full script is provided below.

answer to the question "is the superfish plugin included?"

```
</script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src =
"http://www.synkerainc.com/modules/mod_ext_superfish_menu/assets/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://www.synkerainc.com/modules/mod_ext_superfish_menu/assets/js/superfish.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript">if (jQuery) jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Sorry if I missed some information needed, please correct me and I will send more.

```
<ul class="ext-menu ">
<li class="item-3 deeper parent"><a href="/products-and-services" >Products &amp; Services</a><ul><li class="item-6 deeper parent"><a href="/chemical-sensors" >Chemical Sensing &amp; Analysis</a><ul><li class="item-7"><a href="/solid-state-gas-sensors" >Solid-State Gas Sensors</a></li><li class="item-8"><a href="/integrated-electrodes" >Interdigitated Electrodes</a></li><li class="item-59"><a href="/electronic-modules" >Electronic Modules</a></li><li class="item-104"><a href="/sensor-pricing" >Pricing</a></li><li class="item-120"><a href="/sensors-under-development" >Under Development</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-9 deeper parent"><a href="/ceramic-membranes" >UniKera Ceramic Membranes</a><ul><li class="item-10"><a href="/symmetric-membranes" >UniKera Standard</a></li><li class="item-11"><a href="/asymmetric-membranes" >UniKera UF</a></li><li class="item-12"><a href="/nanocomposite-membranes" >Nanocomposite Membranes</a></li><li class="item-105"><a href="/ceramic-membranes-a-filters-pricing" >Pricing</a></li><li class="item-124"><a href="/ceramic-membranes-under-development" >Under Development</a></li><li class="item-152"><a href="/unikera-membranes" >UniKera Membranes Summary</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-13 deeper parent"><a href="/nanoceramics" >NanoCeramics</a><ul><li class="item-131"><a href="/templates-for-nanofabrication5" >UniKera NanoTemplates</a></li><li class="item-113 deeper parent"><a href="/ceramic-microcomponents" >Ceramic Microcomponents</a><ul><li class="item-115"><a href="/microheatermicrosensor-platform" >Microheater / Microsensor Platform</a></li><li class="item-116"><a href="/microcomponents-for-life-science" >Microcomponents for Life Science</a></li><li class="item-117"><a href="/ceramic-microchannel-plates" >Microchannel Plates</a></li><li class="item-129"><a href="/ceramic-grids-for-electron-microscopy" >Electron Microscopy Grids</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-15"><a href="/substrates-for-bioanalysis-and-cell-culture" >Substrates for Life Science</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="/nanoceramics-pricing" >Pricing</a></li><li class="item-121"><a href="/nano-microfabricated-products-under-development" >Under Development</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-60 deeper parent"><a href="/functional-coatings-and-nanocomposites" >Coating Services</a><ul><li class="item-62"><a href="/ald-on-high-aspect-ratio-structures" >ALD on High-Aspect Ratio and Flat Substrates</a></li><li class="item-63"><a href="/metallized-aao" >Templated NanoArrays</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-107"><a href="/contract-rad" >Contract R&amp;D</a></li><li class="item-100 deeper parent"><a href="/under-development" >Under Development</a><ul><li class="item-122"><a href="/sensors-under-development" >Sensors</a></li><li class="item-123"><a href="/nano-microfabricated-products-under-development" >NanoCeramics</a></li><li class="item-125"><a href="/ceramic-membranes-under-development" >Ceramic Membranes</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-21"><a href="/documentation" >Documentation</a></li><li class="item-22"><a href="/information-quote-request" >Info/Quote Request</a></li><li class="item-103"><a href="/pricing" >Pricing</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-65 deeper parent"><a href="/applicationsandmarkets" >Applications &amp; Markets</a><ul><li class="item-66 deeper parent"><a href="/chemical-sensing" >Chemical Sensing</a><ul><li class="item-67"><a href="/health-and-safety" >Health &amp; Safety</a></li><li class="item-68"><a href="/environmental-monitoring" >Environmental Monitoring</a></li><li class="item-69"><a href="/security-and-defense" >Security &amp; Defense</a></li><li class="item-70"><a href="/portable-and-personal-monitors" >Portable &amp; Personal Monitors</a></li><li class="item-71"><a href="/energy" >Energy</a></li><li class="item-73"><a href="/consumer" >Consumer</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-74"><a href="/materials-and-chemical-analysis" >Materials &amp; Chemical Analysis</a></li><li class="item-75 deeper parent"><a href="/gas-separation" >Gas Separation</a><ul><li class="item-76"><a href="/hydrogen" >Hydrogen</a></li><li class="item-77"><a href="/other-gases" >Other Gases</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-78 deeper parent"><a href="/liquid-filtration" >Liquid Filtration</a><ul><li class="item-79"><a href="/microfiltration" >Microfiltration</a></li><li class="item-80"><a href="/ultrafiltration" >Ultrafiltration</a></li><li class="item-81"><a href="/nanofiltration" >Nanofiltration</a></li><li class="item-84"><a href="/bioseparations" >Bioseparations</a></li><li class="item-83"><a href="/biotech-processing" >Bio Manufacturing</a></li><li class="item-82"><a href="/chemical-processing1" >Chemical Processing</a></li><li class="item-85"><a href="/water-purification" >Water Purification</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-94 deeper parent"><a href="/life-science" >Life Science</a><ul><li class="item-95"><a href="/bioseparations" >Bioseparations</a></li><li class="item-127"><a href="/bioanalysis-a-bio-imaging" >Bioanalysis &amp; Bio-Imaging</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-86"><a href="/templated-nanofabrication2" >Templated Nanofabrication</a></li><li class="item-97"><a href="/clean-and-renewable-energy" >Clean &amp; Renewable Energy</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-4 deeper parent"><a href="/technology" >Technology</a><ul><li class="item-23 deeper parent"><a href="/sensors-overview" >Chemical Sensing</a><ul><li class="item-24"><a href="/chemiresistors" >Chemiresistor</a></li><li class="item-25"><a href="/electrochemical" >Electrochemical</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-26 deeper parent"><a href="/nano-and-microfabrication" >Nano &amp; Microfabrication</a><ul><li class="item-27"><a href="/anodic-aluminum-oxide-aao" >Anodic Alumina</a></li><li class="item-28 deeper parent"><a href="/templated-nanofabrication" >Templated Nanofabrication</a><ul><li class="item-89"><a href="/nanowires-and-nanorods" >Nanowires &amp; Nanorods</a></li><li class="item-90"><a href="/nanodots-and-nanoelectrodes" >Nanodots &amp; Nanoelectrodes</a></li><li class="item-93"><a href="/optical-antennas" >Optical Antennas</a></li><li class="item-92"><a href="/plasmonics-sers-lspr" >Plasmonics, SERS, LSPR</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-29"><a href="/ceramic-micromachining" >Micromachining</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-37"><a href="/intellectual-property" >Intellectual Property</a></li><li class="item-38"><a href="/products-and-services" >Products &amp; Services</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-5 deeper parent"><a href="/company" >About Us</a><ul><li class="item-30"><a href="/vision-and-mission" >Vision &amp; Mission</a></li><li class="item-31"><a href="/history" >History</a></li><li class="item-32"><a href="/our-team" >Our Team</a></li><li class="item-33"><a href="/intellectual-property" >Intellectual Property</a></li><li class="item-98"><a href="/news-home" >News &amp; Events</a></li><li class="item-34"><a href="/careers" >Careers</a></li><li class="item-36"><a href="/contact" >Contact Info</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-40"><a href="/news-home" >News &amp; Events</a></li><li class="item-56"><a href="/store/default" >Online Store</a></li></ul>


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        jQuery("ul.ext-menu").superfish({ 
            animation:  {opacity:'show', height:'show', width:'show'},
            delay:      1000,
            speed:      'normal',
            autoArrows: true 
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the `superfish` plugin?

Comment: This is usually because the library you're trying to use is not included on the page. make sure you have the script with the correct source, or if using AMD to have the path defined and it required somewhere

Comment: I have included the code that might answer the question whether superfish plugin is included in the original post please refer to that.

Comment: does 'jQuery('ul.ext-menu')' actually return an jquery object or an empty array?

Comment: 'jQuery('ul.ext-menu')'  returns a jQuery object, but the object doesn't contain anything called "superfish".  does this mean the module is not properly loaded?

Comment: The error is fixed. It was a conflict between Google analytics and superfish.

thank you for your help